Side effects and undefined behaviour when references are used in a function
We all know that the expression i++ + i++ is undefined behavior.  But is it also UB, if the side effects happen on a reference in the function body?  For example :
int f(int& i) {   // pass by reference
    return i++;  
}

int main() {
    int v=5;  
    auto r=f(v)+ 2*f(v); 
    cout << r <<endl;  
}

When I read the standard, I understand that this is UB:

The standard explains that modifying a value when calling a function can be considered as side effect.  So f() would have a side effect on v :

C++23/[intro.execution]/7: (...), modifying an object, calling a library I/O function, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.


The standard also explains that unsequenced side effects on the same memory location are UB.  I therefore understand that the evaluation of the two operands of + are unsequenced:

C++23/[intro.execution]/10: Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced. (...)
If a side effect on a memory location is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same memory location or a value computation using the value of any object in the same memory location, and they are not potentially concurrent (6.9.2), the behavior is undefined.



Therefore, since both calls to f() modify the same memory location v, I understand it's UB.  However some argue that the execution of the two called function bodies would be  indeterminately sequenced, and not unsequenced, and hence the code would just deliver an unspecified result (17 if left call is executed first, and 16 if the contrary), without being UB.  Can some language-lawyer enlighten me?

Why do you want to operate near UB in the first place? There are always ways to write the code that clearly avoids UB.

I understand it's UB.  It's not UB, but it is the next best thing:  indeterminate behavior.

@JesperJuhl I would indeed not write such code in real projects, and in any doubt I d split in two statements.  I just used an extreme case a minimal viable example for a more realistic code written by someone else.

@Eljay yes, this is what I was being told.  I'm looking for an authoritative argument in the standard ("language-lawyer" tag).

If you need to ask "does this code have UB?", the answer doesn't matter. You need to rewrite it anyway so that the question does not arise. Unless you are writing a compiler, that is. Then you really need to know.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Indeed, I would  not write such code in real projects: in any doubt I split into several statements, add unnecessary parentheses, etc. I just used an extreme case as minimal viable example for a more realistic code written by someone else. Moreover, I have the secret objective to learn something new everyday ;-)

[intro.execution]/11 effectively states that every function invocation happens atomically with respect to sequencing, i.e. multiple function calls can't be interleaved.
Specifically here i++ for the left-hand invocation of f is required to either be sequenced-before or sequenced-after, i.e. indeterminately-sequenced with, all evaluations in the right-hand side call to f, because both happen on the same thread and the former evaluation does not occur within the latter function invocation.
As a result evaluations in different function calls (or different full-expressions in general) can't be unsequenced relative to one-another (if they happen on the same thread).
Therefore this is not undefined behavior. The two i++ evaluations are indeterminately sequenced, so you do not know which happens first, but they are not unsequenced.
There are however two valid observable behaviors, i.e. two different possible outputs, for either ordering of the function call evaluations.

As you say, this is not undefined behaviour (which, essentially, means the standard does not specify any requirements or constraints on what happens).   Your description of "indeterminately sequenced" (essentially, there are a number of discrete events that must happen in some sequence without overlap, but no requirement on the order) is consistent with the definition of unspecified behaviour.   Although some folks may describe this as "indeterminate behaviour", no such thing is defined in the standard.
